# find_by_field not working properly in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a navigation system that provides a permalink for any link setup.

When i run the line through script/console this is what it returns:

```
>> Navigation.find_by_permalink("gems")
=> #<Navigation id: 10, text: "Gems", parent: nil, destination_controller: "pages", destination_action: "show", destination_id: "1", permalink: "gems", created_at: "2009-12-26 14:56:28", updated_at: "2009-12-26 14:56:28", previous: 9>
```

When i put into my app i get this:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in NavigationsController#permalink

 Couldn't find Navigation without an ID
```

My Request was "/permalink/gems" and the associated route is:

```
map.permalink "permalink/:permalink", :controller => 'navigations', :action => 'permalink'
```

The Controller code that handles that request is:

```
def permalink
    @nav=Navigation.find_by_permalink(params[:permalink])
    redirect_to :controller => @nav.destination_controller, :action => @nav.destination_action, :id => @nav.destination_id
end
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Can you please post your controller code? Maybe the param values are not being passed appropriately for one reason or another.

Comment: Did you do a "p" in controller and checked if value for params[:permalink] is coming or not?

Comment: I am having problems retriving the value of params[:permalink], i commented out the current code and added "flash[:notice]=params[:permalink]" and redirected to the root url but i still get the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was caused by Declarative Authorization. It was using the permalink action RESTfully so my navigation find wasnt being used.

To disable Declarative Authorization for all actions bar the RESTful ones in a controller chage:

```
filter_resource_access
```

to:

```
filter_access_to :index, :show, :edit, :new, :create, :update, :destroy
```